# Como implementar corretamente um contador assíncrono no node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou enfrentando dificuldades em implementar um contador assíncrono usando Node.js e MongoDB.

Segue o código:

```js
app.get('/', req, res ()=> {
var number = await Number.find({}); // Leitura do valor
number++;                           // Incrementação do valor               
await Number.save(number);          // Salva valor incrementado
res.send(number);                   // Retorna valor para usuário
})
```

A questão que tenho  é a seguinte: Seria necessário a implementação de um semáforo para a realização dessa tarefa sem que haja condição de corrida ou o Node.js lida com isso automaticamente?

Comment: Seria qual o tipo de condição de corrida e quais os objetos envolvidos?

Comment: Isso poderia ocorrer quando dois ou mais usuários acessassem a uri ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: O nodejs é single thread. As requisições são enfileiradas, mesmo que dois usuários façam a mesma requisição simultaneamente primeiro ele resolve uma requisição e somente após sua resolução ele passa para requisição do outro usuário.